# print user last log-in time using unix

Tags: c, unix-socket

I am fairly new to coding, but here I use a single .c file in putty (UNIX). print below is what I am currently using right now, it prints out the current local time in the format of [YYYY:MM:DD:HR:MN:SEC]. I need to print the client **current user last log time** from the server when I run the client program. Using the same format [YYYY:MM:DD:HR:MN:SEC]. (need to make a custom client/server code to print in the format mentioned, since the shell print out weekday, month, day of month #, hr:min, when using last command).

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <time.h>

#define     DAYSIZE 80
#define     Month 12
#define RCVBUFSIZE 1024   
#define SNDBUFSIZE 1024  



fprintf(stderr, "The last time connected [%d:%s:%d:%2d:%2d:%2d] is the last time when the client program disconnected from the server using the Quit command \n",year,m,wd,hr,mn,sc);
```

Comment: "I need X" is not a question that lends itself to an answer. What are you struggling with? And maybe you should clarify the "last log time" a bit. Do you mean a normal shell login or do you mean some custom client/server thing and the last time a connection was made on that?

Comment: Sorry about that. I need a custom one since the shell would not print it out in that format when I use the 'last' command.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. As I said I am new to this coding stuff, but if anyone looks at this having a similar issue for custom format for log time. You would want to make a file and print the current local time on there and close. Then read that file on rerunning the program. Below is just an example what for just opening a file to write in.

```
//open file name Log.txt then writes in it
fp  = fopen ("Log.txt", "w");   

//what is going inside file
fprintf(fp, "The last time connected [%d:%s:%d:%2d:%2d:%2d]",year,m,wd,hr,mn,sc);  
fclose (fp);
```